# Apache Flink NoSerialization for business logic class

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink with Kakfa where I am able to consume the message properly from topic and deserialize it.

I am using the flink datastream Map function to process the kafka message received but flink expects all my business objects to be serializable.

Below is the pseudo code

```
TestRequestListener listener = this.context.getBean(TestRequestListener.class);
KafkaConsumer<KafkaTestBatch> kafkaConsumer = KafkaSource<>.builder()...build();
StreamExecutionEnviroment env = ...
DataStream<KafkaTestBatch> kafkaSource = env.fromSource(kafkaConsumer,...);
kafkaSource.map(kafkaTestBatch -> {
listener.listen(kafkaTestBatch);
});
```

Here TestRequestListener has business logic where it even queries the database.

Flink expects TestRequestListener and all its dependencies to be serializable.
Is my usecase correct, am I using flink correclty?

Comment: Are you using Springboot libs in Flink ?

Comment: The problem isn't Flink. It's the fact it's running a distributed process. You could move `context.getBean` method call into the `kafkaSource.map`, but then your context variable needs to serializable. Basically, your listeners need to run on the same machine as the mapper function, which would need to be serialized from the driver, here. Why not put the listen function code directly in the map body?

Comment: @Ramachandran Yes

Comment: @onecric I cannot do that there is whole lot of logic

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RichMapFunction` you can instantiate the listener in its `open` method; then you won't have to worry about serializing it.

You should be careful, though, not to do blocking i/o in your Flink functions. It's better to use Flink's [async i/o operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/) for this. For querying a database, you might do better to access the external DB as a [table lookup source](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join) or to stream in its data as a CDC source.

Comment: I am using spring-boot with flink, I am unable to get the TestRequestListener bean in the open method. When I autowire Application Context in my class and send it here it throws my class is not serializable exception or it becomes null.